# How is this subscript notation for Permutation groups read?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I do not understand how the author is trying to write the subscripts of this representation.

[image: Permutation Cycle Decomposition]

Would be read as this:

(a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>2</sub> ... a<sub>m<sub>1</sub></sub>) (a<sub>m<sub>1</sub>+1</sub>  a<sub>m<sub>1</sub>+2</sub>  ... a<sub>m<sub>2</sub></sub>) ... (a<sub>m<sub>k-1</sub>+1</sub> a<sub>m<sub>k-1</sub>+2</sub> ... a<sub>m<sub>k</sub></sub>) .

If that is true, could someone try and explain the use of subscripts in a different way.

Thank you

Comment: I think you got it right.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing much to worry about, it's just a way of showing that there are $k$ cycles. If you prefer, one can write it :

$$ (a_{(1,1)}a_{(1,2)}\dots a_{(1,m_1)})(a_{(2,1)}a_{(2,2)}\dots a_{(2,m_2)}) \dots (a_{(k,1)}a_{(k,2)} \dots a_{(k,m_k)}) $$

where :

- $m_i$ is the lenght of the $i$-th cycle (for instance, for $(3578)$ it's $4$)
- $a_{(p,q)}$ is the $q$-th number of the $p$-th cycle (for instance, with  $\sigma = (12)(34)(56)$,  $a_{(2,1)} = 3)$

Though I'm not sure it makes it more clear...